# Problems with my admin interface

Tags: admin, javascript, ce-1.9.2.1

First of I would like to apologize if there is some rule of this forum I am not following. This is my first post but I am getting desperate, so, here I am.

I already posted this on:
https://community.magento.com/t5/Technical-Issues/Problems-with-backups/m-p/20434#U20434

with not luck. I am not very good on javascript, but it seems that for some reason I am on a construct loop, which makes no sense, cause I am using magento 1.9.2.1 with SUPEE-9788 patch, but I don't believe I did anything to deserve this. :-D

Anyway, I was looking into firebug and it seems there is a construct loop going on and eventually, prototype.js says its too much.

I have no problems on doing the heavy work, but I need help to get going. I don't really know javascript that well, but as I said, I do have firebug and a desperate need to fix this. ;-)

thanks for any feedback.

Comment: HI... I really need help on this. I am testing another instance of magento where I don't have the problem, and there, the javascript is not combined into one big file. Could this be the problem? And how can I stop magento from combining? thanks

Answer (score 0):

So! Mistery resolved! I had under System/Advanced/Developer/Javascript Settings

Merge Javascript file = YES

I thought it would improve site performance with that. IT DOESN'T and it creates a bad and big javascript that doesn't work. I will open a ticket for the developers, but for me this issue is closed.

Sorry for bothering everyone and I hope it helps others.

Thanks
Fred